# [ink!]How to get the latest confirmed block hash?

Tags: ink

Is there any way to get the latest block hash in ink! smart contracts?

I'm wondering if the `ink_env::random(subject: &[u8])` can do it if I pass an empty `subject` to it?

Comment: Can you describe the use case in which you see the need for the latest block hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an empty subject: `self.env().random(&[])` you will get back a hash and the block number "since which it was determinable by chain observers". So something like this:

```sh
(Hash([14, 226, 146, 230, 25, 164, 171, 91, 28, 230, 150, 50, 244, 69, 169, 102, 18, 186, 225, 160, 102, 54, 167, 68, 43, 11, 153, 41, 122, 155, 26, 103]), 55672)
```

- https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.random.html

The block hash is not currently exposed.

You do have access however to the [block number](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.block_number.html) e.g. `self.env().block_number()`, you can also use a chain extension to grab the block hash if you really need it, or take the block number and deduce the block hash from that..

Comment: i've written a Flipper game in Solidity where you can access the previous block hash with `blockHashPrevious = blockhash(blockNumber - 1);` https://github.com/ltfschoen/XCMTemplate/pull/23/files#diff-fa4375dc6e580dc8d5e6d1ddcf56f920463f91207238f27c792f70a02cc2b061R88. i understand that ink! is an improvement on Solidity so i'm writing it in ink! but is it really an improvement to access the block hash for a given block using a chain extension? how would you deduce the block hash from the block number as you have mentioned that is a possibility?

Comment: i've written that same Flipper Game in ink! now but i don't know how to access the previous block hash using ink! here https://github.com/ltfschoen/XCMTemplate/pull/23/commits/45fb06a75e02e151603959cbc85a5740d04d6221#diff-dadc6f64a8f75c0d9e8a5b20470f1bb875998addafe1b7700eb03af00e7226bdR214